# give node author ability to position the image when uploading content

Tags: 7, users, media, nodes

I have a field of type image "COVER IMAGE" in my blog entry content type. The users should have the power to place it wherever they like...top, down,right or left, if not more and re size it. right now it appears at the bottom of the content and of the same size as that uploaded.

Can this be done?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it can! Was [covered in docs](http://drupal.org/node/176828) and in [even more docs](http://drupal.org/node/163346) and is supported by [Wysiwyg](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg), with helpful modules like [Insert](http://drupal.org/project/insert) to make it even easier.

Comment: 59924 sites have Insert installed and I've never even heard of it. Must be good! I didn't think of the WYSIWYG approach, good call

Comment: It's dirt simple, just gets the job done. It's not so hard to generate img tag in javascript, after all. I'm just glad some other guy maintains it's browser compatibility!

Comment: brilliantly put

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Formatter Field](http://drupal.org/project/formatter_field) module for the second part

> The formatter field module provides a mechanism for specifying a formatter and formatter settings to be used for displaying a field, on a per-entity basis. By default, Drupal provides formatters and settings per entity bundle, but in certain situations it is necessary to choose the formatter at the entity level.
>
> For example, say you have a page node with an image field. Normally, you would select an image style as the formatter, and all page nodes would use that same image style. With this module, you can add a formatter field to page nodes, which is hooked up to the image field. Then when the node is created or edited, the image style can be selected per-node.

Comment: Pure Wysiwyg solution allows to display image as smaller, leaving file intact. Good thing about is: it's less resource intensive on node save, and allows for unpredicted formats. Good thing about module you provided - saves bandwidth and reader's resources. "Choose your poison" case, as good in one = bad in the other.

Comment: If it's for non-admin users I think I'd prefer the WYSIWYG solution, I don't know of an intuitive module for arranging fields on a page-by-page basis (display suite/panels can get there but I've never liked the interfaces personally)