# How to create pages with images in the content?

Tags: media, nodes

I'm trying to create a page with content that looks like this:

[image: the layout that I'm trying to create]

I'm using CKEditor to edit the content, and it allows me to add images to the article. However, the images need to be already present at some URL.

Is there a way I can upload an image (the image of the doctor with a pad) to my drupal site separately, and then use its URL to insert the image in my article?

In other words, how do I upload just an image to my drupal site so that it can be used elsewhere?

Comment: possible duplicate of [give node author ability to position the image when uploading content](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73706/give-node-author-ability-to-position-the-image-when-uploading-content)

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this.

Have two regions, one with the content (ie the left blurry blob). And one called sidebar. The sidebar region would have a block that you would add the right image. And a block (which I assume would be something like a view or maybe it's manually added) to do the Related Links.

Then you could have a content header region for the top part.

So you would end up with

```
|  Content Header  |
| Content | Sidebar|
```

Or at least that is how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just install the [IMCE](http://dgo.to/IMCE) module, which will allow you to upload images and insert them into CKEditor/WYSIWYG fields. You can use the IMCE module regardless of whether you want to insert the image into your content node directly or make a separate block.